# GL_INVALID_VALUE in glUseProgram on resuming app

Tags: c++, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone, shader

I am getting `GL_INVALID_VALUE​, 0x0501` error at `glUseProgram(mYUVProgram);` in the following code. It occurs on resuming the app. According to [glUseProgram docs](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glUseProgram.xml)

> GL_INVALID_VALUE is generated if
>       program is neither 0 nor a value
>       generated by OpenGL.

I want to know how I can check the value of `mYUVProgram`, whether its valid or no, after the app has resumed. So that I can create the shader program again if `mYUVProgram`'s value is invalid. (I am just beginner in OpenGL so please forgive me if this question is too trivial)

**CODE**

```
void draw() {
 if (!mFrameTexture) {
    glGenTextures( 1, &mFrameTexture );
    mProgram = Shaders::addProgram(this, (char *) Shaders::vertexShader,
                                                 (char *) Shaders::fragmentShader);
    //other initialization code
    CCLOG("draw:: added shader");
 }

  glUseProgram(mYUVProgram);
  //other drawing code
  }
```

Comment: "*So that I can create the shader program again if mYUVProgram's value is invalid.*" The question you *really* need to ask yourself is *why is it invalid*. You should *never* have invalid programs just lying around. If the program is invalid, then your code has done something wrong.

Comment: _Yes_. I would like to know exactly what happens when the OpenGL context is saved. Whether all objects and programs in the context are saved properly, and how they are re-loaded when the application resumes. And whether I have to take care of any things manually when this happens. Any pointers on where I might find this specific information ? Thanks @NicolBolas

Comment: Nothing happens when the context is saved, because there is *no function to do that*. You cannot serialize an OpenGL context or otherwise preserve its data. Unless you're using some tool outside of OpenGL to "save" the context, in which case you should ask that tool.

Comment: Ok. I am actually using the cocos2d-x framework on android. So if OpenGL is not saving the context by default then its either cocos2d-x or android that I must dig into, to find the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct me if I am wrong , but I believe this is what you are looking for?

http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glIsProgram.xml

eg.

```
if ( glIsProgram( mYUVProgram ) != GL_TRUE ){
  // Recreate mYUVProgram
}
 glUseProgram( mYUVProgram);
```